# Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

So I've come across an issue on one of the sites that I've had for a while and out of the blue, it just stopped working. I'm receiving an event handler error when clicking on the blog posts in my iScroll module.

Below, I will provide screenshots (***All clickable sections on there aren't clickable all of a sudden***):
[image]

**Browsers**:
*Internet Explorer*: Works OK - No problem.
*Edge*: Works OK - No problem.
*Firefox*: Works OK - No problem.
*Chrome*: Throws `Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event.` error - Links unclickable.

**What I'm using**:
`/*!
 * iScroll v4.2.5 ~ Copyright (c) 2012 Matteo Spinelli, http://cubiq.org
 * Released under MIT license, http://cubiq.org/license
 */`

**Problem**:
Throws the `Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.` error in console - Links unclickable.

Everything worked well prior to today, so I'm not sure what could have caused it to all of a sudden stop working. It's saying that it's throwing the error from the official minimized `jQuery.js` file.

This is the library that the previous developer is using: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Chrome has set all event listeners that are related to page scrolling to `passive` by default a few months ago, against the web specification. This means you can't prevent the default action (scrolling) of the event. Have you tried using the latest version of the plugin? It looks like a fix might have been added.

Comment: Looks like I have the iScroll v4.2.5 version installed, wonder if that's the latest.

Comment: That's from 2013, latest is 5.2.0 from 2016. Edit - but I don't think that will solve it because I noticed the issue being reported in 2018. I'll have a look at the source code if it can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much @Shikkediel, let me know if you find any further details.

Comment: Thanks so much for that @Shikkediel, tried applying it to the iScroll.js file and I'm still receiving the `Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event.` violation which sucks because it's only not working on Google Chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195714/discussion-between-sema-and-shikkediel).

Comment: One more try [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/bsB6JkGJ). I semi-tested this on an existing Codepen. Script I posted earlier had several errors but this does seem to remove the warning when emulating touch events on Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

The answer comes from here: [Making wheel scrolling fast by default](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/scrolling-intervention)

> Breakage and Guidance :
> In the vast majority of cases, no breakage will
> be observed. Only in rare cases (less than 0.3% of pages according to
> our metrics), unintended scrolling/zooming might happen due to the
> preventDefault() call getting ignored inside the listeners that are
> treated as passive by default. Your application can determine whether
> it may be hitting this in the wild by checking if calling
> preventDefault() had any effect via the defaultPrevented property. The
> fix for the affected cases is relatively easy: pass {passive: false}
> to addEventListener() to override the default behavior and preserve
> the event listener as blocking.

If you are getting warnings like the ones you see you need to specify the `addEventListener()` calls as `passive`.

You can do that like this :

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener, {passive: true});
```

If you need to stop propagation or do a call to `event.preventDefault()` in the `listener` that is fired you should specify `{passive: false}` instead of `{passive: true}`.

This is mandatory because a `passive` option set to `true` prevent any call to `event.preventDefault()` in the related `listener`.

Doing so will make those warnings disappear as long as the requiring `addEventListener()` calls got their `passive` option set.

**Take note that this may not work for all browsers so some changes may be required.**